# /Date(long + 1000)/ format

Tags: java, json, date, datetime, date-parsing

does anyone know what type of date format is it, and how can I parse it properly to Date object? I get it from server in a Jason response.

```
{ "DateFirstListed":"\/Date(1438218663000+1000)\/" }
```

Comment: see here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use the part before the +1000

it's a standard unix time stamp with milliseconds. I'm not sure what the +1000 is for but likely it's just to offset the time by 1 second. (1000 ms)

so paste `Date(1438218663000)` in your browser console and you'll see

`"Tue Oct 20 2015 21:27:39 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"`

It could possibly be intended to be a Human Friendly url so that it can be stored in unix time, but you can use

`/articles/Tue Oct 20 2015 21:27:39 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)` as a url. But in any case, it's just unix time.

EDIT: +1000 (thanks Sasha) probably means UTC+10:00, so you could create your date like this

`new Date(new Date(1438218663000).getTime()+10*60*60*1000)`

Comment: `+1000` very likely means UTC+10:00 (10 hours)