# Parsing non UTC date with DateTimeFormatterBuilder

Tags: java, jackson, java-time

I am trying to parse the following date string received from a [Bitbucket event payload](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver0516/event-payload-966061436.html?utm_campaign=in-app-help&utm_medium=in-app-help&utm_source=stash#Eventpayload-pullrequest):

```
2017-09-19T10:39:36+1000
```

When the incoming date is in offset `+0000` then it works but `+1000` does not.

This is a slightly non-standard (from the JDK's perspective) date string in that it has no colon in the offset. So I have made a custom DateTimeFormatter that works when the offset is `+0000`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
    .optionalStart()
    .appendOffset("+HHMM", "+0000")
    .optionalEnd()
    .toFormatter();
```

However, when the offset is `+1000` as above, it fails with:

> Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.OffsetDateTime` from String "2017-09-19T10:39:36+1000": Failed to deserialize java.time.OffsetDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2017-09-19T10:39:36+1000' could not be parsed at index 19

If the received date string is using offset `+0000` then it works. How can I parse all time zones?

#### Update - Extra context:

This is being used to construct an instance of JavaTimeModule used to inform the ObjectMapper of the incoming date format:

```
JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
    .optionalStart()
    .appendOffset("+HHMM", "+0000")
    .optionalEnd()
    .toFormatter();
// This also fails:
// DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssx");
LocalDateTimeDeserializer deserializer = new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(formatter);
javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, deserializer);
// MAPPER is an instance of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
MAPPER.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
```

Comment: which version of jackson you are using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250878/datelong-1000-format 
the +1000 means its formatted in UTC+10:00

Comment: I am using the Jackson bundled with Dropwizard 1.3.7. And, yes, +1000 means UTC+10:00. I'd like to parse that and other time zones

Comment: As mentioned in the seemingly now deleted answer - that works standalone but not when used as shown in the context update above. The JavaTimeModule added to the ObjectMapper does not accept it.

Comment: please provide the object you are deserializing using jackson MAPPER

Comment: I cannot reproduce. [See your code running online here](https://ideone.com/ippi15).

Comment: As an aside, is there any point in specifying the offset as optional? You need one for constructing an `OffsetDateTime`. Isn’t there always an offset in the string from the Bitbucket event?

Comment: This may be related to running with the Dropwizard bundled Jackson libraries. I’ll do some standalone experiments to see if it works. As for the optional offset - I don’t know why I did it that way initially. I’ll make it non-optional.

Answer (score 0):

For parsing +1000 this below code will work.

```
package com.iamninad.qa;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateTimeDeserializer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class TimeFormat {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        System.out.println(dateTimeFormatter.parse("2017-09-19T10:39:36+1000"));
        LocalDateTimeDeserializer deserializer = new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(dateTimeFormatter);

        JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
        javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, deserializer);
        ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
        MAPPER.registerModule(javaTimeModule);

        // serialize object

        String s = MAPPER.writeValueAsString(new Data());
        System.out.println(s);

        // deserialize object

        String json = "{\"date\":\"2017-09-19T10:39:36-0830\"}";
        String json1 = "{\"date\":\"2017-09-19T10:39:36+1000\"}";

        Data data = MAPPER.readValue(json, Data.class);
        System.out.println(data.toString());

        Data data1 = MAPPER.readValue(json1, Data.class);
        System.out.println(data1.toString());
    }

}

class Data {
    // Just to generate a sample data
    private DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    private LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-09-19T10:39:36+1000", dateTimeFormatter);

    public LocalDateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data{" +
                "date=" + date +
                '}';
    }
}
```

If you want to parse +10:00 then use ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME for fields in format +10:00 or pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` it will either be in any one format. I guess this issue is resolved in jdk 9

```
OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-09-19T10:39:36+10:00")
```

Also parses time in only one format i.e +10:00 and not in +1000 you need to specify formatter to `parse` method

```
OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-09-19T10:39:36+1000",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"))
```

Comment: Can it be used with the formatter from the question? Asking because I like the reuse of `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`.

Comment: only if it's +0000 format or no +0000 at the end , +00:00 won't work

Answer (score 0):

The `Z` pattern can parse that offset. Have you tried to use this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
        .appendPattern("Z")
        .toFormatter();
```

It can parse `+0000` and `+1000`.

Comment: Thanks, as mentioned above my problem is not reproducible for others so trying standalone Jackson not bundled with Dropwizard and will update with findings